# Turn nested for into a one-liner in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this nested for-loop that I am having difficulty turning into a one liner. What is the best way to eliminate the nested for? Thanks.

```
 for (const house of this.houses){
   for (const room of house.rooms){
   this.plans.push(room.layout.id);
  }
 }
```

Comment: If you've got a list of "house" objects, and each one has a list of "room" objects, you're kind-of stuck with a nested loop one way or another.

Comment: Your above code will work fine in one line.   What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can remove the line breaks. Most line breaks in JavaScript are optional. This way you can turn most codes into one-liners. Your code as a one-liner `for (const house of this.houses){
   for (const room of house.rooms){
   this.plans.push(room.layout.id);
  }
 }`

Comment: Your code is easy to read and maintain and does only the work needed.  Why do you want to turn it into a one-liner?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could map the nested `id`.

```
this.plans = this.houses.flatMap(({ rooms }) => rooms.map(({ layout: { id } }) => id));
```

For better readability:

```
this.plans = this.houses.flatMap(({ rooms }) => rooms
    .map(({ layout: { id } }) => id)
);
```

Comment: This code has 3 lines, not 1.

Comment: @jabaa, right. for readability.

Comment: Yes, every code has multiple lines for readability, or at least I don't know any other reason to add line breaks. This question explicitly asks for a one-liner. If your code isn't readable in one line, you've probably not answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
this.houses.forEach(house => house.forEach(room => this.plans.push(room.layout.id)))
```

forEach calls a function for each item in an array.

Comment: There's still a nested loop, but yes. Note that this might not perform better than the plain loops in the OP, as there are function calls involved.